# German municipality-level data (Gemeinde) on demographics

Tags: city, germany, census

I'm trying to find comprehensive Gemeinde-level data for small (<10'000 inh.) municipalities in all of Germany.

The (joint-)distribution or at least some summary shares of the following characteristics is most important for me:

- Gender
- Education
- Age
- Migratory background

I've found some data from the zensus2011 (https://www.destatis.de/DE/PresseService/Presse/Pressekonferenzen/2013/Zensus2011/zensus_pk.html) but this - if I understand correctly - has no Gemeinde-level info on education, and I'm not sure if it's comprehensive (i.e. containing ALL Gemeinden in Germany). I am also happy if you point me to other data sources/Gemeinde-level data sets.

PS: this request is related [List of German local politicians](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5352/list-of-german-mayors)

Comment: You can get it at least by population directly as geo data from the German Government (Bundesamt für Kartographie und Geodäsie (BKG).) here: http://www.geodatenzentrum.de/geodaten/gdz_rahmen.gdz_div?gdz_spr=deu&gdz_akt_zeile=5&gdz_anz_zeile=1&gdz_unt_zeile=18&gdz_user_id=0 There are some nice shape files available.

Answer (score 3):

I came across an overview of employees (including demographics such as gender and migratory background) provided by the employment agency. Unfortunately one needs to pay 36 EUR to get it. Please check the following [Excel](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=2ahUKEwjgg4ic2q3eAhVJI8AKHZ3BCuEQFjADegQIBhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstatistik.arbeitsagentur.de%2FStatistikdaten%2FDetail%2FAktuell%2Fiiia6%2Fsozbe-gemband%2Fgemband-d-0-xls.xls&usg=AOvVaw1MvHKVdwFt0gcv65pKZTLH) for more details.

And there is another source that might be even more helpful. Check https://www.regionalstatistik.de. The topic number 12 (Bevölkerung) includes some of the information you are looking for. Have a look under Statistik 12411 (Fortschreibung des Bevölkerungsstandes).