# List of German local politicians

Tags: government, city, germany

I am looking for a dataset/list of all mayors of German municipalities. In particular I am interested in smaller municipalities (<10'000 inhabitants).

I care most about the following data

- Age
- Party affiliation
- Time in office

But data containing partial or additional info are fine too

PS: This is related to this question: [German municipality-level data (Gemeinde) on demographics](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/5350), but since the answers would be distinct I am creating a second question.

Comment: What's the link with the other question?

Comment: It's for the same project, i.e. uses the same unit of observation and will be merged eventually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elections for the the mayors in German municipalities are organised by the respective states and the *Landeswahlleiter* of the state publishes the results.

For the state of Saarland, the mayor elections can be found here:

http://www.statistikextern.saarland.de/wahl/internet_saar/BM_SL/

The data contain: Date of election, all candidates with affiliations, detailed vote turnout. They do not contain gender or age of the candidates.

For the other states, searching "Landeswahlleiter `<name of the state>`" brings you close to the results. You may need some German knowledge (or at least a dictionary) to navigate the pages; often no other language versions are provided.

Comment: This worked. In some states better than in other's, and in some (Lower Saxony, Baden Württemberg, Schleswig Holstein) not at all.